# How to make the document.write(); not add on text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<script>
function makeWindow() {
    var result = window.open("", "Result", "width=600,height=600");
    result.document.write(document.getElementById("txt").value);
}
</script>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<br>
<button onClick="makeWindow();">Click</button>
```

If I type "Hello, World!" inside the textarea, when I press the button it makes a new window saying, "Hello, World!". But, if I delete everything in the textarea(not the window) and type "Hello again!", instead of getting the result of "Hello again!", I get the result of "Hello, World!Hello again!" Could someone please help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short solution:

`result.document.body.textContent = document.getElementById("txt").value`

`document.write()` in general is discouraged, there are much more sophisticated ways to manipulate the contents of a window. Google **"HTML DOM"** (Document Object Model) to read up on how HTML elements work in JavaScript; the MDN website generally has pretty good materials.

Answer (score -1):

Máté Safranka is right to discourage `document.write`, but if you do want to know how to do it with `document.write`, all you need to do is add

```
result.document.close();
```

after

```
result.document.write(document.getElementById("txt").value);
```

And the each time `makeWindow` is called, it'll have to reopen the document, blowing its current contents away.